# Regex not matching the content between the new lines (\r\n)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using Regex for the first time, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question..

I'm trying to match this input string with regex:

```
   string input = "\r\n+CMGL: 3,\"REC UNREAD\",\"+999999999\",,\"21/07/15,14:06:38+08\",145,10\r\nTest1\nTest2\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
    
   Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",,""(.+),(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
```

I have no problem matching the first part of the input with this code:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",,""(.+),(.+)");
```

But I cannot find the way to match this last part: **\r\nTest1\nTest2\r\n**

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem is that you forgot to consume the `,145,10` text on the line with double quotes, you are trying to match the line break immediately after the last `"`.

You can consume them with `.*` and add another `(.*)` to match the `Test2` line:

```cs
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""([^""]+)"",""([^""]+)"",,""([^"",]+),([^""]+)"".*\r\n(.+)\r\n(.*)\r\n");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%2BCMGL%3A%20%28%5Cd%2B%29%2C%22%28%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%22%2C%22%28%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%22%2C%2C%22%28%5B%5E%22%2C%5D%2B%29%2C%28%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%22.*%5Cr%5Cn%28.%2B%29%5Cr%5Cn%28.*%29%5Cr%5Cn&i=%0D%0A%2BCMGL%3A%203%2C%22REC%20UNREAD%22%2C%22%2B999999999%22%2C%2C%2221%2F07%2F15%2C14%3A06%3A38%2B08%22%2C145%2C10%0D%0ATest1%0D%0ATest2%0D%0A%0D%0AOK). See the *Table* tab:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I just had to change your solution a little bit.. to match the split between Test1 and Test2 with \n and not \r\n. Otherwise it didn't work in C#.

Comment: @RegexHelp The online regex testers always normalize line endings. At regexstorm, it is CRLF, and at regex101, it is always LF. I would suggest `\r?\n`, but `.` also matches a CR char. In that case, you'd also need to replace `.` with `[^\r\n]`. So, if you know there is a single LF between `Test1` and `Test2`, then use `\n`.